# Should I delete old zero-score answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm sure every one of us has answers that just never went anywhere.  In some cases, I'm sure we all have answers that we posted to questions where another answer was accepted and got a positive score, whereas our answer got zero score. In my case, the reason is obvious: Good material gets upvotes... :)  Just kidding.  It's part of the system; it's how it *should* work.

The question is, in such a case, should I delete my answer?  It isn't serving any purpose: if no one has upvoted it after a few months, it's clear that it didn't add anything to the post, and it isn't really all that helpful.  Is this kind of answer unnecessary clutter?

Comment: I would think the answer is no.  You may have the best answer and over time it could float to the top.  I've had a few of those, not many, but a few.  That's my first thought at least.

Comment: I have 31 "0 vote" answers. I had *never* considered deleting any of them.  I'd highly suggest you not worry about it. Someone, sometime, will find them useful and upvote it, or as @Ellesedil stated, people will find the answer useful but won't have an account to upvote you. Really, it's not "unnecessary clutter" at all. Keep up the great work!

Comment: BTW, I downvoted you because this is a bad idea for you to do. Please don't take personal offense to the downvote ... it just means I don't agree with you doing the nasty on your old stuff! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, sure, that's fair.  I do agree, too.  I kind of wrote this post on a spur of the moment inspiration:  I guess another question along the same tack that was playing in the back of my mind was whether others would be less likely to post better answers than mine because they see there is/are already (an) answer(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users who come from a search engine won't be able to upvote your answer, yet may find the information they were in fact looking for. Upvotes isn't the ultimate indicator of usefulness. As long as your answer isn't wrong, I'd leave it. And if it ends up helping people who are registered or later join the site, you may slowly accumulate upvotes.

Comment: I agree full heartedly!